# wp-accordion slider css incorrectly makes font appear bolder in IE9

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am using a wp-accordion slider in one of my clients web sites. The css below is for the slide title, but when I look at the slider in IE it makes the font look much bolder.

```
.css-vertical-text {
    color:#333;
    border:0px solid red;
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    bottom:30PX;
    width:220px;
    height:205px;
    font-size:18px;
    margin-left:10px\9;
    font-family: trebuchet ms;
    // text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #333;
    filter: flipv fliph;
```

}

Please help. I've tried using `font-weight`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try using a different font?

Comment: What does that line `margin-left:10px\9;` do? Different browsers render same font differently, so I wouldn't worry too much. Unless it's a really big difference.

Comment: To accompany your code, can you provide a link to the site or create a http://jsfiddle.net recreating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try below css , it may help you

```
   font-weight:normal !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
font:normal 18px !important;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but Still it looks bold,

Comment: could you provide the html where you are actually applying this css. i will help a lot if you provide the jsfeddle.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because IE's `filter` property doesn't work correctly...[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhHHA/2/)

**Edit**

Ignore my ramblings about HTML5. We're obviously talking about CSS3. Still, it doesn't look like IE supports it.

**Edit2**

Even worse, I looked into it some more and it turns out that the new CSS3 `filter` property isn't what we're talking about. Instead, IE used to have an IE only CSS property called `filter`. I'd try to see if it works on IE browsers prior to IE 9 but they won't work with jsfiddle. I'd give up on using something that isn't standard to achieve your effect.